# Entropy for linear advection-diffusion equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, entropy, linear-pde

> Let u be a solution to $$u_t+cu_x=\epsilon u_{xx}$$
>   with $\epsilon>0$, $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that for any convex function $\mu \in C^2(\mathbb{R})$ the total entropy $\int_\mathbb{R}\mu(u(x,t))\,\text dx$ is a non increasing function in time.
>   You may assume that $\mu(u)$ falls off at $|x|\to\infty $ as fast as you wish.

What I have so far:
I multiplied the PDE with $ \mu_{u}$ to get $\mu_{u}u_t+\mu_{u}cu_x=\mu_{u}\epsilon u_{xx}$, which leads to
$$
(\mu(u))_t + (\mu(u))_x-\epsilon ((\mu(u))_x)_x+((\mu(u))_x\, \mu_{uu}\,(\mu(u))_x)=0 .
$$
And because $\mu$ is convex, $((\mu(u))_x)_x+((\mu(u))_x\,\mu_{uu}\,(\mu(u))_x)\geq 0$ and so i get the inequality
$$
(\mu(u))_t + (\mu(u))_x-\epsilon ((\mu(u))_x)_x\leq 0
$$
I have a clue that I need to integrate this with respect to $x$ to get to
$$
\frac{\text d}{\text d t}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mu(u)\,\text dx\leq 0
$$
but why do the other terms disappear? And what exactly does "fall off" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several algebra mistakes or typos in OP's derivation. From multiplying the PDE by the derivative $\mu'(u)$ of $u\mapsto \mu(u)$, we obtain
$$
\mu(u)_t + c \mu(u)_x = \epsilon \left( \mu(u)_{xx} - \mu''(u)\, {u_x}^2 \right) .
$$
Integrating over $x\in \left]-X, X\right[$, we have
$$
\int_{-X}^X \mu(u)_t\,\text d x + c\, \left[\mu(u)\right]_{x=-X}^{x=X} = \epsilon\, \left[\mu(u)_x\right]_{x=-X}^{x=X} - \epsilon \int_{-X}^X \mu''(u)\, {u_x}^2\,\text d x .
$$
If $\mu(u)$ and $\mu(u)_x$ vanish as $|x|\to +\infty$, i.e. $\mu(u)$ "falls off" fast enough, taking the limit $X\to \infty$ in the previous identity leads to
$$
\frac{\text d}{\text d t}\int_{\Bbb R} \mu(u)\,\text d x = - \epsilon \int_{\Bbb R}\mu''(u)\, {u_x}^2\,\text d x < 0 ,
$$
due to the convexity of $\mu$.